# How to change doc file in PDF using Php code .

Tags: php, localhost, server

I am working on PHP project where there is need to convert a file with extension(.xls/.xlsx/.doc/.docx) to PDF file. 
Please tell me is this possible and how we can achieve this .

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [PyOdConverter](https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter). You must install openoffice on the machine.
With openoffice the machine is able to handle ms office documents.
With the PyOdConverter you can convert them to PDF-Files via PHP.